# Does Writing Linux Kernel Module Require Compiling Own Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a simple hello world kernel module on Ubuntu x86_64:

```
#include <linux/module.h>

static int 
mod_init(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "RYANhello world\n");
  return 0;
}

static void 
mod_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "RYANgoodbye world\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
CUR_DIR := $(shell pwd)
obj-m := module.o

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(CUR_DIR) modules
```

When I `sudo insmod module.ko` I get `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Invalid parameters`. Inspecting `dmesg`:

```
loading out-of-tree module taints kernel
module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Repeating `insmod` yields `module is already loaded` however `/var/log/syslog` shows no trace of it loading (i.e `printk` messages not present). Also, running `sudo rmmod module.ko`:

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/module/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
```

This seems to indicate it's not loaded, even though `dmesg` says it is?

Addressing common issues; my host kernel and gcc version are the same as ones I compiling with.

So, this leads me to think that the module not being signed is the issue. To disable this do I have to compile and install my own kernel with appropriate `.config`? In other words, to write and test your own kernel modules on a modern GNU/Linux OS with enforced signing, do you have to compile and install your own kernel?

**EDIT**
`CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE` is not set in my `/boot/config-5.8.0-53-generic`, so it seems I should be able to load my module albeit with a tainted kernel message. So, why would I be getting `Invalid parameters?`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/483283/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing ls this of any help?

Comment: @ChristinaJacob `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE` is not set in my `/boot/config-5.8.0-53-generic`, so it seems I should be able to load my module albeit with a `tainted kernel` message. So, why would I be getting `Invalid parameters`?

Comment: Check if the module unloading is supported  in the kernel . The kernel is build with this flag MODULE_UNLOAD

Comment: @Varun `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` is set in my kernel.

Comment: @RyanMcClue any dmesg print when doing rmmod. The print you have given for rmmod are from userspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting `dmesg` on first `insmod` it was saying that the module was already loaded. As I had never loaded this before, this prompted me to think that this name was already taken.
Low and behold, renaming `module.c/module.o --> example.c/example.o` fixed the problem. The `invalid parameters` message was what threw me.